# I am trying to assign the 2d array image to arraylist compressedImageVList, but getting out of bound error

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am trying to assign the 2d array image to arraylist compressedImageVList, but getting out of bound error!
What might be wrong. Kind of new to this concept of arraylist.

// compress image method
    public static void compress(short[][] image){

```
    // get image dimensions
    int imageLength = image.length;   // row length
    int imageWidth = image[0].length; // column length


    // Creating array list compressedImageXXX since the size is unknown

  //just checking
  ArrayList<Short[]> compressedImageVList = new ArrayList<Short[]>();



    //short oldValueVertical;
    //short counterVertical;

   for (int i=4;i<imageLength; i++){
     for (int j=0;i<imageWidth; j++){
          compressedImageVList.add(image[j][i] );
     }
   }

   for(int i=0;i<compressedImageVList.size();i++){
     System.out.println(compressedImageVList.get(i)+ "");
   }
```

}
}

Comment: Watch out for your indices in first loop. Change  compressedImageVList.add(image[j][i]); to compressedImageVList.add(image[i][j]);

Comment: Sidenote: the problem has nothing to do with `ArrayList`s; @CemOzer correctly has it that the problem is with array `image`.

Comment: actually i want my loop to go vertically down, not move horizonatlly so! I have problem at this part:compressedImageVList.add(image[j][i] )

Comment: @CemOzer: you should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT2: Your loop should be like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<imageLength; i++){
    compressedImageVList.add(image[i]);
}
```

This will add every second level array into your arraylist.

---

Change `compressedImageVList.add(image[j][i]);` in first loop to `compressedImageVList.add(image[i][j]);`. This is the cause of out of bound error.

EDIT: You also comparing i in your second loop, this loop will cause an infinity loop, also a out of bound error. You must compare j in here.

Comment: i want to move down the 2d array i.e from [4][0] to [5][0] and son on. That's why i put [j][i].

Comment: First of all the case is iterating over an 2d array, you must take care of indices properly. If you want to push down array by one line, you must use [i+1][j]. If you can give us a visual example of before/after array, we can help you more.

Comment: i am saying nothing to do like i+1; i am just trying to move down vertically. from row 4 to 5, 6, 7 and son on.